Botonos y texto en XML no visibles por el scrollView
Tengo el siguiente XML en el cual tengo muchos edit text dentro del scroll view, tengo un boton de registrarse y dos text view con información para ir al inicio se sesión. El problema es que cuando relleno alguno de los edit text de el scroll view desaparecen estos campos, y si los pongo encima del scroll view siempre quedan arriba del teclado opacando el campo. ¿Qué podría hacer para solucionar este problema? Los textos que quiero que se mantengan se encuentran dentro del relative layout de la parte inferior del código, puede que la solución sea modificando algún parámetro de éste o directamente en los textview y el botón
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".register_sell"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo_grande"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"


    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunit_negrita"
            android:text="Empieza a vender"
            android:textColor="@color/verde"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.373"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.201" />


        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
            android:layout_width="410dp"
            android:layout_height="439dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nombreText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="51sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunit_negrita"
                    android:text="Nombre *"
                    android:textColor="@color/verde"
                    android:textSize="17sp"

                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/nombreField"
                    android:layout_width="319dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_normal"
                    android:hint="  "
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/verde" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/errorNombre"
                    android:layout_width="334dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_muynegrita"
                    android:text="Es necesario rellenar este campo"
                    android:textColor="@color/red"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/apellidosText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="51sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunit_negrita"
                    android:text="Apellidos *"
                    android:textColor="@color/verde"
                    android:textSize="17sp"

                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/apellidosField"
                    android:layout_width="319dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_normal"
                    android:hint="  "
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/verde" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/errorApellidos"
                    android:layout_width="334dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_muynegrita"
                    android:text="Es necesario rellenar este campo"
                    android:textColor="@color/red"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/emailText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="51sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunit_negrita"
                    android:text="Email *"
                    android:textColor="@color/verde"
                    android:textSize="17sp"

                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/emailField"
                    android:layout_width="319dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_normal"
                    android:hint="  "
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/verde" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/errorEmail"
                    android:layout_width="334dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_muynegrita"
                    android:text="Es necesario rellenar este campo"
                    android:textColor="@color/red"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/contraseñaText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="51sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunit_negrita"
                    android:text="Constraseña *"
                    android:textColor="@color/verde"
                    android:textSize="17sp"

                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/contraseñaField"
                    android:layout_width="319dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_normal"
                    android:hint="  "
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/verde" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/errorContraseña"
                    android:layout_width="334dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_muynegrita"
                    android:text="Es necesario rellenar este campo"
                    android:textColor="@color/red"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cifText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="51sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunit_negrita"
                    android:text="CIF *"
                    android:textColor="@color/verde"
                    android:textSize="17sp"

                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/fieldCIF"
                    android:layout_width="214dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="51sp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_normal"
                    android:hint="  "
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/verde" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/errorCIF"
                    android:layout_width="334dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_muynegrita"
                    android:text="Es necesario rellenar este campo"
                    android:textColor="@color/red"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cuentaText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="51sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunit_negrita"
                    android:text="Número de cuenta bancaria *"
                    android:textColor="@color/verde"
                    android:textSize="17sp"

                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/cuentaField"
                    android:layout_width="223dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="51sp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_normal"
                    android:hint="  "
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/verde" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/errorCuenta"
                    android:layout_width="334dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_muynegrita"
                    android:text="Es necesario rellenar este campo"
                    android:textColor="@color/red"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />


                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                    android:layout_width="314dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="51sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_normal"
                    android:text="Estoy de acuerdo con los términos y condiciones"
                    android:textColor="@color/verde"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/errorTerminos"
                    android:layout_width="334dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_muynegrita"
                    android:text="Es necesario rellenar este campo"
                    android:textColor="@color/red"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="413dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_normal"
                android:text="¿Ya tienes cuenta?"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.94"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.144" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/loginText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunit_negrita"
                android:text="INICIA SESIÓN"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.94"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.595" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/registerButton"
                android:layout_width="151dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="231dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:elevation="30dp"
                android:text="Regístrate"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>```



Únicamente con android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" no esta funcionado?

Lo he intentado pero no funciona :(
